# Static matrix passed to cudaMemCpyToSymbol

Tags: pointers, matrix, cuda

I want to use constant memory with a statically allocated matrix. I declared the constant matrix as follow:

```
 #define MASK_WIDTH 5
 #define MAX_MASK_WIDTH 10
 __constant__ float M[MAX_MASK_WIDTH][MAX_MASK_WIDTH];
```

In the `main()` function have a statically allocated matrix as follows:

```
    float h_M[MASK_WIDTH][MASK_WIDTH] = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 },
    { 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 },
    { 3, 4, 5, 4, 3 },
    { 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 }
};
```

And I must pass the `h_M` matrix to the follow function:

```
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M, h_M, sizeof(h_M));
```

That is defined in: [cudaMemCpyToSymbol](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g9bcf02b53644eee2bef9983d807084c7)

How can I correctly do it? Consider that I must initialize the matrix with specific values, so I think that I can't declare it and allocate dynamically.
The problem is that the `cudaMemCopytosymbol` has no effect, after the copy all values in `M` are zeros.

If you need the complete source code, it is at the following link: [cached_convolution_2D_basic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SimoGira/CUDA/master/cudaExercises/chapter07/cached_convolution_2D_basic.cu)

Comment: Your link is dead. Also, please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. As it is right now, it will be difficult to reason about why your results may be off from what you are expecting.

Comment: I added the source code, it works perfectly if I declare and initialize the constant memory as I made in the host code, so the problem is in the cudaMemCpy that fails when I pass it the h_M matrix.

Comment: The link to `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` does not work

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M, h_M, MASK_WIDTH*MASK_WIDTH*sizeof(float));
```

what you have is broken:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M, h_M, sizeof(sizeMask_Width));
```

`sizeof(sizeMask_Width)` is asking the compiler "what is the size of the variable called `sizeMask_Width`?  That is an `int` variable so the answer is `4`.  So that call would only transfer 4 bytes.  You should have just done this:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(M, h_M, sizeMask_Width);
```

because `sizeMask_Width` is the same as `MASK_WIDTH*MASK_WIDTH*sizeof(float)`  which is the actual correct number of bytes you need to transfer.

I think in your case `sizeof(h_M)` would have worked also, but for future readers, that depends on the specific definition of `h_M` here.  That might not work in other slightly different cases.

Comment: Sorry it was only an error cause of cut and paste... I solved my problem and soon I'll post the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Problem [Solved]
The problem was that I thought as a matrix layout instead of raw major layout.
See the image below:
[image]

The M array has a size: MAX_MASK_WIDTH * MAX_MASK_WIDTH, instead the h_M array has a size: MASK_WIDTH * MASK_WIDTH. So when I call the cudaMemCpyToSymbol function it copies the h_M matrix in raw major layout order into the M matrix.
One can solve the problem in different ways:

1. declaring the matrices of the same dimensions
2. declaring both M and h_M matricies (in this case) as unidimensional
   vectors with different dimensions as it was initially, but using
       `M[i * MASK_WIDTH + j]` into the kernel code.